# some suggestions for analyzing two-factor within subject design?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, repeated-measures, spss, counterbalancing

I'm doing a two-factor within-subject design experiment, and the two factors are all categorical variables. factor one has four categories, while factor two has two categories, and is counterbalanced. this lead to a 2*4=8 conditions. the dependent variable is a continuous variable such as reaction times.

my data is in a long format as follow

```
ID     Trial   factor1    factor2    reaction time
 1       1       1          1           3.142
 1       2       3          1           4.543
 1       3       4          1           2.456
 1       4       2          1           3.433
 1       5       4          0           3.142
 1       6       2          0           4.543
 1       7       3          0           2.456
 1       8       1          0           3.433
 ...
 2
 2
 2
 ...
 50
 50
 ...
```

my first question is, is it possible to run a regression analysis? (IV: two categorical variables  DV: a continuous varible)

my second question is , is it possible to run a regression analysis for the total participant (like 50 persons) as a whole as the same as a single person?